# Remove unnecessary fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

We are populating Elasticsearch via logstash. The thing is that I see some unnecessary fields that I had like to remove like for example:

```
@version
file
geoip
host
message
offset
tags
```

Is it possible to do this by defining/extending a dynamic template? If yes, how? If no, can we do this via logstash configuration?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove fields using really any logstash filter - when the filter succeeds, it will remove the field.

It makes sense to me to use mutate:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "file" ]
    }
}
```

That said, most of these fields are incredibly useful and really should not be removed.

Comment: If you have a whielist of fields you'd like to keep, you can also use the prune filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html